# Getting a url segment from a route

Tags: pyramid, pylons

For this route:

```
config.add_route('item_get', '/item/{id}', request_method='GET')
```

What is the easiest way to get the **{id}** part from a view that uses this route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dictionary is added to the `request`, called [`request.matchdict`](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/urldispatch.html#the-matchdict):

```
id_ = request.matchdict['id']
```